# Windows 10 slow boot and shutdown after anniversary update

Tags: windows-10, boot, shutdown

After installing the Windows 10 anniversary update, my computer boots very slow. The first part of booting (bios, loading Windows) is as fast as it used to be, but after logging in I'm stuck on a black screen with just my cursor for over a minute before it seems to continue with the login.

I made a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EDXKQUKxiYA&feature=youtu.be) to explain what I mean.

Also, when I shutdown, Windows says that Spotify is blocking the shutdown - Which is strange because why would Spotify do this? It will stay on this screen for about a minute until it just gives up and I'm back on my desktop with everything except Spotify shut down. If I click 'Force shutdown' or close Spotify before shutting down, everything works fine.

EDIT:

I have done some boot traces as requested by @magicandre1981 and @nijave -- They have now been removed because they were eating up my Google Drive storage.

I don't get this issue when the computer reboots, only when it's completely shut down and started again later. So I'm not sure the traces are of much help.

Comment: Install the WPT (part of the Win10 SDK: https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/windows-10-sdk), run WPRUI.exe, select **First Level**, **DiskIO**, **FileIO** and under **Performance Scenario** select **Boot**. **Number of iteration** can be set to **1** and click to start. This reboots Windows and captures all activity during boot. After the reboot let the countdown tick to 0 to capture 2 minutes of activity after boot. Zip the large ETL file into zip/RAR file, upload the zip (OneDrive, dropbox, google drive) and post the share link here.

Comment: @magicandre1981 I've added them, the issue doesn't happen when rebooting so I'm not sure how useful they'll be though :(

Comment: @cascer1, those don't seem right. You generally get an ETL file of around 700-800+ MB uncompressed but those are small folders that appear to debugging/symbol files instead. Here's a pic of the interface http://i.imgur.com/0lCOiK5.png

Comment: @nijave yeah, that's the interface I used. I zipped the entire output folder and uploaded it. I'll try again tomorrow!

Comment: @cascer1 here's a random image I found online of what the file looks like. It's just a single file with an ETL extension (if you have Windows Explorer configured to show file extensions). It will have an icon that looks like that image http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-FLUp2ehbL4Y/U1RSEWS3yCI/AAAAAAAAANU/Cs21L5_qYIA/s1600/output2.png

Comment: @nijave Looks like I got it right this time, I did three boot traces (figured I'd just let it run a few times as I brushed my teeth and stuff) and the total size is about 15 GB now. Looks like I just zipped the incorrect item for the other two since it did actually produce those .etl files too. I'll update the post once the upload completes. [that may take a while though](https://ducohosting.com/screenshots/D_y4O5PjrQ_y4O5PjrQ.png)

Comment: most of boot time is post boot (loading all programs at startup). also the 840 Evo had perf issues with old data. make sure you use the latest firmware. also using a ssd/hdd combination causes issues in version 1607: http://www.winbeta.org/news/windows-10-anniversary-update-freezing-microsoft-offers-workarounds

Comment: look if you use the latest firmware of the 840 Evo. for the windows issue, we have to wait. look if the firmware fixes the issue

Comment: I'm already running the most recent firmware, I'm afraid :(